# Apach redirecting https 443 to https with custom port like 3128

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, port

I am using Apache web server in front of Squid proxy server on the same machine, and got SSL certificate from Letsencrypt and Apache server now is trusted green site.
I changed the htaccess file to suit my needs to reach Squid server behined Apache in two cases with https or without it . So my htaccess file as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if not https Redirect all requests to Squid except for Let's Encrypt's   ACME Challenge verification  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://backend.squid.server:3128/$1 [R=301,L]


# if https on Redirect all requests to Squid except for Let's Encrypt's ACME Challenge verification  

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://backend.squid.server:3128/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first part  is redirecting well with no problems and I got the respnse from squid server.
but when we send the same request but with https I got the following error

> An error occurred during a connection to backend.squid.server:3128.
>   SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>   Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG .

what I have on Squid.conf if that may help:

```
https_port 3128 cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.tld/fullchain.pem key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.tld/privkey.pem

http_port 3128 act-as-origin name=server accel vhost
```

I think the problem in redirecting from https 443 to https with a custom port. 
If anyone has dealt with such an issue Please tell me where is the problem ? what is the right syntax for this in htaccess file